# Selenium C# Logging Preferences incompletely implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium.WebDriver.Chrome 2.40.0

According to the documentation the following is allowed

```
var co = new ChromeOptions();
co.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
co.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Client, LogLevel.All);
co.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);
co.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Profiler, LogLevel.All);
co.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Server, LogLevel.All);
```

However, when I actually try to access the `Client`, `Server` and `Profiler` logs I get (on stderr)

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 56426
Only local connections are allowed.
[1529414019.263][WARNING]: Ignoring unrecognized log type: client
[1529414019.266][WARNING]: Ignoring unrecognized log type: profiler
[1529414019.266][WARNING]: Ignoring unrecognized log type: server
```

Having access to these three log objects would be helpful. How do I access them, if at all?

**Extra Detail**

According to the documentation about [LogType](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_LogType.htm), there are 5 possible values: `Browser`, `Client`, `Driver`, `Profiler` and `Server`. Tarun Lalwani has suggested (see comments) there's also a `Performance` but I can't see any sign of that.

I don't understand why the documentation says there are five, but operationally there's only `Browser` and `Driver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the [canonical answer](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/www.seleniumhq.org/issues/189) is (drum roll) ...

> Those listed are only the possible log types. For instance, server
>   will only be available if you're using a server that implements this
>   log (such as selenium-server). You can see which log types are
>   available from your endpoint by using the GetAvailableLogTypes method

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the ChromeDriver source code

https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/5c38bafbf04d6196493d4bec1a851b45a1c07d12/chrome/test/chromedriver/logging.cc#124

```
}  // namespace
const char WebDriverLog::kBrowserType[] = "browser";
const char WebDriverLog::kDriverType[] = "driver";
const char WebDriverLog::kPerformanceType[] = "performance";
bool WebDriverLog::NameToLevel(const std::string& name, Log::Level* out_level) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arraysize(kNameToLevel); ++i) {
    if (name == kNameToLevel[i].name) {
      *out_level = kNameToLevel[i].level;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

It only supports `browser`, `driver` and `performance`. And for the other ones you get a warning, which is correct

Comment: A few questions in response: The supplied code refers to a "Performance" metric; where do I find that in the Selenium C# docs? Also the code appears to come from an "experimental" tree (if the path is anything to go by), so which Selenium WebDriver.Chrome will I find it in?

Comment: This is chromedriver source code and not C# so not sure what you looking in C# docs?

Comment: See "Extra Detail" above. Please note that the title of the question and the tags indicate that the context is C# and .NET, so quoting me experimental chromedriver source code (is it C++ ?) isn't helping.